# Logging into sudo in expect failing - BASH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

Here is my expect script that a bash script calls on:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/expect -f
  2 
  3 set timeout 1
  4 set user [lindex $argv 0]
  5 set pw [lindex $argv 1]
  6 
  7 spawn ssh $user@remotehost.com
  8 expect "$"
  9 send -- "cd /opt/Data/\r"
 10 expect "$"
 11 send -- "sudo su runtime\r"
 12 expect "*?assword for*"
 13 send -- "$pw\r"
 14 expect "$"
 15 send -- "./run.sh\r"
 16 expect "$"
 17 send -- "exit\r";
 18 send -- "exit\r";
 19 exit
```

My results are:

```
user@localhost:~/Documents/scripts$ ./bashscript
Enter your web password: 
spawn ssh user@remotehost.com
Last login: Tue Dec 10 11:10:37 2013 from user@localhost
[user@remotehost.com ~]$ cd /opt/Data/
[user@remotehost.com /opt/Data]$ sudo su runtime
[sudo] password for user: user@localhost:~/Documents/scripts$
```

Notice the last line, I'm not sure why the password is not passing. Any ideas?

Comment: Try:sudo -S          The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from
                the standard input instead of the terminal device.

Comment: At line 12, are you sure that it is what you expect ? Can you try : expect "*?assword"

Comment: Always use `exp_internal 1` while developing expect scripts. Expect will show you whether the pattern matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do this without expect: See if your system's `sudo` has a `-S` option, which reads the password from stdin.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$2" | ssh "$1"@remote sudo -S sh -c ./run.sh runtime
```